# Need help to debug the code using jadclipse plugin via eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I'm currently using Jadclipse eclipse plugin to dis-assemble the code when the source is not attached to the eclipse.

I'm not clear how to make it sync and debug the same.

Could someone help me with the steps as well as comments in detail?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Kathir

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether Eclipse is able to synchronously read codes decompiled by Jadclipse as debug source. I guess it probably not.

As so, I advice you manually de-compile these codes and save it to local source files, link them to source in Eclipse, after that, try using remote debug mode to debug your code. this is the way I always did.